# unexpected result for @value in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Javadoc seems to only process `@value` tags on classes declaring the referenced fields and only references without the classname.

**Example:**

I have the classes

```
/** {@value #F} */
public class A {
    public static final String F = "field";
}
```

and

```
/** {@value A#F} */
public class B {}
```

The jdk 1.7 javadoc tool processes the `@value` tag on `A` but for `B` I get the following warning:

```
warning - A#F (referenced by @value tag) is an unknown reference.
```

This waring also occures when I try to reference the field in the javadoc of `A` with `A#F`. When I use a `@link` tag instead everything works as expected.

I could not find any documentation mentioning that the `@value` tag may only reference Fields declared in the class the javadoc is on.
Is this a bug or is there another way to get the `@value` tag to display the value?

Comment: Are A and B in the same package? Or does B import A?

Comment: They are in the same package and as I said, it also fails if I use `A#F` in the javadoc on `A` directly.

Answer (score 5):

Providing whole package name with referenced class solves my problem:
Assuming class A is defined in package com.example, this works for me:

```
/** 
* {@value com.example.A#F} 
*/
public class B {}
```

Hope it helps.